# PHP - How to send HTML through SoapClient

Tags: php, serialization, soap

Every time I send html string using SoapClient, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] 
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:
There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter ...
```

Example:

```
$productData = [
    'id' => 123,
    'name' => 'ProdName',
    'description' => 'This product is just <b>AMAZING!</b>'
];

$ws = new \SoapClient(...);
$ws->ProductUpdate($productData);
```

So, how could I send html data through it?

Comment: Try to wrap it in <![CDATA[ ... ]]>. Example: <![CDATA[This product is just <b>AMAZING!</b>]]>

Comment: @RemcoK. Thanks! I will try it